# Be notified about an APNS notification when app is in background WITHOUT background notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have subscribed to APNS notifications in my Swift iOS app.

I am only interested in user-facing notifications, so i have not setup a background mode.

If the app is open, the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`'s `userNotificationCenter:willPresent:withCompletionHandler` is called. If the app is in the background AND the user taps on the notification (which opens my app by default) `userNotificationCenter: didReceive: withCompletionHandler` is called.

However, if the user simply dismisses the notification in the notification center, then my app doesn't know that the notification was delivered.

Is it possible to somehow inspect which notifications were delivered when app was in the background or killed and that user hasn't tapped on, upon app launch?

Comment: Do you control the payload of the notification? If you can put 'mutable-content' in the aps dictionary you can use a UNNotificationServiceExtension. The extension will get notified before a notification is displayed. You don't have to edit the notification but you'll be able to save any info about it that you want.

Comment: @Simon this is genius, actually! Worked a treat, although i've not passed an Apple review yet, but at least i can definitely get the notifications through shared app groups into the main app even when the user didn't tap on them. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Added as an answer, thanks. Apple will be fine with it. They don't know you don't have any intention of modifying the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you control the payload of the notification?

If you can put 'mutable-content' in the aps dictionary you can use a UNNotificationServiceExtension.

The extension will get notified before a notification is displayed.

You don't have to edit the notification but you'll be able to save any info about it that you want.